# DisplayPort to HDMI adapter works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, adapter

A few months ago I bought a second monitor for my desktop computer. The monitor I bought is the same model as my main monitor (Samsung T35F). My GPU is an AMD RX 6700XT which only has one HDMI output, so I had to buy a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter in order to plug my new monitor to the GPU.

The problem is that when I'm using Windows, the second monitor is not detected (to be precise, the monitor connected via the adapter is not recognized). I run a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 and Linux Mint, and when I'm using Linux Mint both monitors work flawlessly, which leads me to believe this is a software related problem and not a hardware related one.

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling GPU drivers (using DDU).
- Reinstalling Windows 10.
- Power cycling the monitor.
- Power cycling the computer.
- Switching the HDMI cables.
- Disabling HDCP from AMD Adrenalin.
- Changing how multiple displays are shown from the Win+P menu.
- Disabling Fast Boot.
- Setting the energy mode to high performance.
- Enabling/disabling Freesync on both monitors.

Comment: 1. Is the video refresh rate set the same on Windows and Linux? 2. Have you tried to change that rate in Windows OS? 3. Have you tried switching monitors, rather than cables, to see if the issue is there, though unlikely, since they're identical.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik
1. Yes, it is set at 75 Hz on both Windows and Linux.
2. Yes, I've tried using 60 Hz and 75 Hz on Windows.
3. Yes, but the issue is still there. The monitor connected via HDMI works while the one connected via the adapter doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried another DisplayPort to HDMI adapter?

Comment: @harrymc Maybe I doubt the adapter is the problem, as when I use Linux the monitor works flawlessly. However, I will try to get a new adapter in the following days and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @harrymc Well, I bought a new adapter and no luck. I also tried another monitor of the same model (a third one) to see if it helped but no luck either. I am truly clueless.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried seeing if your drivers need to be updated? Press `Start Menu` + R and type devmgmt.msc to open the device manager. Then click on "Ports (COM and LPT) to and see if your display port plug is there. If it is, double-click it, click the "Driver" tab, and click update drivers. If there is an update for your drivers, your computer will install it. If that don't work,, let me know in the comments.

Comment: The only port that I can see under "Ports (COM and LPT)" is "Communications Port (COM1)" (the exact wording may be slightly different as my system isn't set to English), I don't see any DisplayPort plug.

Comment: Okay. In the device manager, try expanding the display adapters menu. Then double-click anything in the menu and go to the "drivers" tab and click "update drivers" until your display port adapter works.

Comment: Ports in the device manager is Not where you'll find display port ports. This answer demonstrates a significant misunderstanding of the computer and the question.